# JavaScript is not working on ASP MVC Project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.net MVC, I recently switched from PHP MVC (Codeigniter).

So I have some issue with ASP.
Actually I have a template of admin panel and I converted dashboard.html page to index.cshtml and call in from HomeController.
Page is open perfectly but JavaScript is not working means when I click on profile tab it opens a popup with edit profile or logout in dashboard.html (from template). But it is not working in index.cshtml that I had converted.

I put all template required JavaScript, CSS etc. in Content folder and set this to all src and href.

Page showing like template but JavaScript is not working.
I worked with this template on PHP Codeigniter MVC, there was no issue.

I checked 10 times but could not found any issue.

File Path :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/_demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure,the file path is correct?did you open it in browser console?

Comment: I added file path above please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `src = @Url.Content("~/link")` with the link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content(~/Content/js/_demo.js")></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery.min.js")></script>
```

Comment: Right now i have changed my Js folder from Content to Scripts folder. And it works perfect but i confused what it means?

Comment: Thanks @Yuvette.  It's working But i am confused what it means ? I was used  `src="~/Content/js/_demo.js">` that is not working why ? can you explain it.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

> `<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/content/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")%>"></script>`

it's working on asp.net web forms